# Error:" Property 'registry' does not exist on type 'LoopBackApplication'"

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

Unable to create a model using app.regsitry.createModel(name, property,options)

```
app.registry.createModel('TenantCreateOneReq', {  
  'feature_map': {  
    'type': 'number',  
    'id': true  
  }  
}, { base: 'PersistedModel' });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var app = loopback();

loopback.createModel('TenantCreateOneReq', {  
  'feature_map': {  
    'type': 'number',  
    'id': true  
  }  
}, { base: 'PersistedModel' });
```

Try like this